# Null Reference Pointer error at WriteableBitmap when trying to save image in WP7

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, writeablebitmap, isolatedstoragefile

Not sure why, and two days of trying different things I'm getting nowhere.  Keep getting the NRP at the WriteableBitmap line. You can see I've tried to both close and flush (and both together) the stream.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
 IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Selections.xml", FileMode.Open));
        MyClass enclaves = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
        enclavesList.ItemsSource = enclaves.Collection1;

            foreach (XElement xencl in document.Descendants("rest"))
               {

            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            String theelement = xencl.Element("couplink").Value;
            String nameElement = xencl.Element("coup").Value;
            String uriring = theelement.ToString();
            Uri uri = new Uri(uriring, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(enclavesDownloaded);
            downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);

            using (IsolatedStorageFile newIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                String tempJPEG = randomNumber.ToString();

                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = newIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);
                //fileStream.Close();
                //fileStream.Flush();
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("" + uri ));
                image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
              }
           }
         }
```

I've googled till I'm blind and not sure what to do now.
Thanks in advance all you folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add handlers to the image before the "new BitmapImage" line, like so:

```
this.Image.ImageOpened += ImageOpened;
this.Image.ImageFailed += ImageFailed;
```

Then, in the ImageOpened event, save to the WriteableBitmap:

```
private void ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)sender);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile newIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            String tempJPEG = randomNumber.ToString();

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = newIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);
            //fileStream.Close();
            //fileStream.Flush();
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("" + uri ));
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
          }
}
```

You are currently attempting to save the image before it has loaded, hence the null pointer exception.

Comment: Thanks philorube.  Took a bit of reorganizing my code, but that was the call, along with adding a forward slash during the final file save.

Comment: Glad I could help! I had a similar problem a while back. :)

Comment: Well that worked but my new code is not quite right, executed a second parsing method in the loop to get the strings and it won't iterate... Have to figure out how to do a custom event to pass the strings and such to the handler.. The examples at MS really are not good at all. Do you have any of those hints in your bag of tricks?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you're trying to do? Are you trying to save images in succession?

Comment: Basically what it does is to download a xml file with app data, four text fields (two are download urls for the image files) and two image files per choice.  The user selects from a list of 20 to 30 choices, usually selecting 4 to 5.  The images are small.  The goal is to have both the xml file and the images locally stored, want to avoid needing a net connection every time the app is used.
The issue seems to be passing the download url from the foreach method to the event handler.  Have tried doing a second iteration/parse in the event, just wrote the same file over the selections.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for all who have tried to download multiple images to isolated storage and keep the names of the file on the WP.  Notice that it requires a url path with the file name from the xml file that is first downloaded, strips the path then saves the file with the original name.
Borrowed some code (Thanks to all, especially philorube), wrote other and cursed a LOT to get here, but it works.

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage =   IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        XDocument document =    XDocument.Load(myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Selections.xml", FileMode.Open));
        MyClass enclaves = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());


        foreach (var xe in document.Descendants("couplink"))
        {
            mane = xe.Value.ToString();
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri(mane, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
            webClient.OpenReadAsync((uri),mane);
        }
    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count;
        Stream stream = e.Result;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String imgName = (string)e.UserState;
        String cleanImgName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imgName);
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(cleanImgName, FileMode.Create, isf))
            {
                count = 0;
                while (0 < (count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)))
                {
                    isfs.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                stream.Close();
                isfs.Close();
            }
        }
```